# TypeScript Union Types usage with Conditional (ternary) Operator

Tags: typescript, types, interface, union

I receive a cryptic error message when using two custom Typecsipt types  `'OptionsPostData3 | OptionsPostData4'` (temporary name sorry)  and a ternary operator when using only `OptionsPostData3` or only `OptionsPostData4` one half or the other half of my code is not getting an error message ...

#### My code look like this

```
const postData: OptionsPostData3 | OptionsPostData4 =
      !!optionIds && optionIds.length > 0
        ? {
            optionIds,
          }
        : {
            filters: [
              {
                underlyingId,
                expiryDate,
                optionType: optionType || void 0,
                minstrikePrice: minstrikePrice || 0,
                maxstrikePrice: maxstrikePrice || 0,
              },
            ],
          };
```

I have not been lucky trying to find a solution online and probably it is obvious (or maybe not) to find a solution in the cryptic error message but I don't know what I should do ...

#### The types are defined like this

```
export type OptionsPostData3 = {
  filters: Filters[];
};
export type OptionsPostData4 = { optionIds: number[] };

export interface OptionsIdArray {
  optionIds: number[];
}

export interface FiltersArray {
  filters: Filters[];
}

export interface Filters {
  underlyingId: number;
  expiryDate: string;
  optionType: string;
  minstrikePrice: number;
  maxstrikePrice: number;
}
```

I think that the error message may provide enough information to solve my problem but I did not find how... And I want to avoid using the `any` type keyword  :

#### The Error message looks like this

```
Type '{ optionIds: number[]; } | { filters: { underlyingId: number | undefined; expiryDate: string | undefined; optionType: string | undefined; minstrikePrice: number; maxstrikePrice: number; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'OptionsPostData4 | OptionsPostData3'.
  Type '{ filters: { underlyingId: number | undefined; expiryDate: string | undefined; optionType: string | undefined; minstrikePrice: number; maxstrikePrice: number; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'OptionsPostData4 | OptionsPostData3'.
    Type '{ filters: { underlyingId: number | undefined; expiryDate: string | undefined; optionType: string | undefined; minstrikePrice: number; maxstrikePrice: number; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'OptionsPostData3'.
      Types of property 'filters' are incompatible.
        Type '{ underlyingId: number | undefined; expiryDate: string | undefined; optionType: string | undefined; minstrikePrice: number; maxstrikePrice: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Filters[]'.
          Type '{ underlyingId: number | undefined; expiryDate: string | undefined; optionType: string | undefined; minstrikePrice: number; maxstrikePrice: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Filters'.
            Types of property 'underlyingId' are incompatible.
              Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

if you need the full project as a reference  [this is the GitHub link, it starts on line 20](https://github.com/Luxcium/questrade-ts/blob/4f36e77ad019215dca11b1236dac15b11372f44a/src/api/core/_marketsQuotesOptions.ts#L20)

Comment: Can you share the full code? What are values like `underlyingId` and `optionIds` set to?

Comment: **Full code is provided as the last line of my post:** [If you need the full project as a reference this is the GitHub link, it starts on line 20](https://github.com/Luxcium/questrade-ts/blob/4f36e77ad019215dca11b1236dac15b11372f44a/src/api/core/_marketsQuotesOptions.ts#L20)

Comment: I get the error on that very page without having to set or assign any values to   `underlyingId as number` or to `optionIds as number[ ]`

Comment: Check the call signature, most of the values do not match what's defined in `OptionsPostData3 `. https://github.com/Luxcium/questrade-ts/blob/4f36e77ad019215dca11b1236dac15b11372f44a/src/api/core/_marketsQuotesOptions.ts#L12-L17 For example, saying `underlyingId: number;` but the signature says it can be undefined. Try assigning defaults or loosening the types in `Filters` to allow `undefined`, `null`, etc

Comment: @skovy what is odd to me is that If I say const postData: OptionsPostData4  =
      !!optionIds && optionIds.length > 0` ... the first part (first half) pass  or if I say `   const postData: OptionsPostData3  =
      !!optionIds && optionIds.length > 0
        ` ... the last part (second-half) pass

Comment: if you want to formulate it as an answer I will mark it (I just added `?` in the interface)
 `export interface Filters {
  underlyingId?: number;
  expiryDate?: string;
  optionType?: string | undefined | null;
  minstrikePrice?: number | undefined | null;
  maxstrikePrice?: number | undefined | null;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [arguments in your function signature](https://github.com/Luxcium/questrade-ts/blob/4f36e77ad019215dca11b1236dac15b11372f44a/src/api/core/_marketsQuotesOptions.ts#L12-L17) that are used to construct the object do not match the defined interfaces. The two options are to loosen the types in your `Filters` interface, or narrow the argument types to match those in `Filters` (eg: add defaults / remove the possibility of `undefined`.

```js
interface Filters {
  underlyingId?: number;
  expiryDate?: string;
  optionType?: string | null;
  minstrikePrice?: number | null;
  maxstrikePrice?: number | null;
}
```